# Can't install Ubuntu on my computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, live-usb

I have a 16GB USB that I burned the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .iso to using Rufus on my Windows 7 computer. I booted from USB multiple times, changing the USB port, I tried it with UEFI and without.

My PC is a i7 4790, Gigabyte H97-HD3, 2 2TB hard drives and 120 GB SSD (OS driver for Windows 7)

Comment: and what happens?

Comment: It goes black and stays black, waited 5 minutes +. I have a Nvidia graphics card - GTX 780 connected through DVI.

Comment: Try installing the iso on the USB with something like unetbootin and see if that helps.

Comment: That didn't work, unetbootin couldn't even burn it properly

Comment: Well what happened?

Comment: Unetbootin just didn't burn it for me

Comment: that's not an answer to what happened. If you don't tell me what went wrong then can I tell you what to fix?

Comment: What format is the USB in? is it NTFS or fat32?

Comment: Fat32 is the format I used

Comment: hmm, should work...

Comment: but it doesn't...

Comment: have you tried another USB? another computer? another version of Ubuntu? another program? etc..

Comment: I have the same motherboard. And according to http://www.gigabyte.co.id/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4954#sp, it requires special driver to run Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended utility for burning a bootable image is the [univeral USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) (referenced by http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).  I've tried and failed with Rufus before.